# React Router v4: Prevent navigating back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im building this app where a user can book an appointment. Its a multistep process so the users makes some choices along some routes, lets call them "/route1", "/route2", "route3" and finally after the booking is completed they get navigated to a "/confirmation" route where they can see all the details of their booking.

If the user presses the back button on the browser at this stage, I want to either redirect them to the index page or rather first display a confirm message telling them that they can't go back at this point, and if they still want to, they will get navigated to index page.

I saw that react-router has a Prompt component, but I cant configure it to navigate to a certain path. It only allows the user to either stay, or continue the navigation.

Any tips for how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

React prompt have parametr 'when' that makes Prompt action conditional. You can set boolean value in state (if true - Prompt active), something like this

```
class MyComponent extend React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         isNavigationBlocked: false;
      }
   }

   render(){ 
      return (<div>
      <Prompt when={this.state.isNavigationBlocked}/>
      </div>)
   }
}
```

And change this state in some handler.

Comment: But I want to prevent the user from navigating back. Showing a prompt still gives the user  a choice to confirm that they do indeed want to navigate back, which is exactly what Im trying to prevent. If I were to somehow show a prompt, and the user confirms, then i want to navigate to "/" instead of "/route3" which would happen in your example above.